# Should API and message consumer be in the same microservice?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, distributed-system

My team is torn with how we should architect our microservices with using a message bus.

We currently have an API Gateway with many microservices behind it all communicating over http.

After looking into implementing Message Buses (Kafka) the team is torn on whether the consumer and API should live in the same service or if they should be two separate services.

Some think they should be separate as they have different scaling concerns, while others think they should be in the same service since they are communicating with the same database and have the same domain concerns. IE) Not duplicating code between two services.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: could you give me a concrete example for this: "the consumer and API should live in the same service"?

Comment: Say I have an e-commenrce site... I may have a Payment service that can list customer payments from its api, and also listen to order_create events on the message bus to process events.

That would be a concrete example of an api and message conumer in the same service (I'm not saying it's the right approach).

Comment: so, you are asking if the microservice would process queries and also process commands?

Comment: Yea, that's a good point. If commands come in the form of events and queries come in the form of api requests, I guess that is what I'm asking. I'm familiar with CQRS, perhaps we should think about it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this is that the Webapi should be in one process and the Message Consumer should be in a separate process. However, the **collective of the two processes is ONE Microservice**. That is, you should deploy them together as one unit and you can share the domain between the two (as it is still one microservice).

The above microservice example is still focused on **ONE business capability/bounded context** , even though it is made up of two processes.

I think it's important to make the distinction between Business Capability and Software Capability when thinking about bounded contexts. The processes in the example above may have different software capabilities (one takes in web requests and one consumes messages), but together they complete a single business capability.

Comment: Well said. This is exactly how I've done it successfully years later! Great answer.

Answer (score 3):

We prefer them to be in the same service as they logically are doing work on same objects.

This also highly depends upon how you write your business logic. Like we prefer here to write our business logic in Aggregates(Domain Driven Design) and that's why writing consumer in the same service makes sense.

In some case where they are just updating data for searching kind of things , you may write them in separate service.

You can also look at [Lagom](https://www.lagomframework.com/) (microservices framework for java)